# Make Connection Pooling on Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to make connection pooling on MongoDB. I am on node environment and using mongoose package for interaction with MongoDB.
I am able to interact with one instance of MongoDB.

How I can interact with two instance of MongoDB?

Two instances will be on different port

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1/db1', { useMongoClient: true });
var db = mongoose.connection;
```

This is my Implementation of interacting with MongoDB one instance.

Comment: I'd assume that using different variable names would allow you to use two different instances at the same time. I could be wrong, though.

Answer (score 1):

There is two way to connect to mongodb database using mongoose.

---

**The one you are using**

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1/db1', { useMongoClient: true });
var db = mongoose.connection;
```

The `connection` object is stored directly into the `mongoose package`.

---

**The other**

```
  const connection1 = mongoose.createConnection(url, opt);
  const connection2 = mongoose.createConnection(url, opt);

  connection1.once('open', () => {
      // We are connected
  });

  connection2.once('open', () => {
      // We are connected
  });
```

Where the connections objects are handled directly by yourself

---

See the **Multiple connections** part in [mongoose documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html)

Comment: How I can Set the port on these Two Mongo instances. Like My first DB server run on Port 27017 while another one is on Port 27018.?

Comment: This is a part of the `url` parameter. For example `mongodb://${username}${ip}${port}/${databaseName}`

Comment: NEUT and Thanks Buddy For Suggesting. I forgot to thanks

Comment: Like This "mongodb://Abhay/127.0.0.1:27018/color_db"?

Comment: `mongodb://127.0.0.1:27018/db1` using your own example. I have an username in my example due to the fact I'm using authentifiacation